# Uploading a file using Node without changing to a new page

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload

I've been following some tutorials on how to upload a file using node and I've had success in actually uploading the file (I've primarily used https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/file-uploading-in-node-js/).  However, every time it uploads the file, it changes to a new page.  Is there a way to stay on the same page after uploading the photo, or do I have to create an HTML file with the same name with the same HTML as before the upload?  The working code is below:

```
const express = require("express") 
const path = require("path") 
const multer = require("multer") 
const app = express() 

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));


var storage = multer.diskStorage({ 
    destination: function (req, file, cb) { 
        cb(null, "uploads") 
    }, 
    filename: function (req, file, cb) { 
      cb(null, file.fieldname + "-" + Date.now()+".jpg") 
    } 
  }) 
    
var upload = multer({  
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: function (req, file, cb){ 
        var filetypes = /jpeg|jpg|png/; 
        var mimetype = filetypes.test(file.mimetype); 
  
        var extname = filetypes.test(path.extname( 
                    file.originalname).toLowerCase()); 
        
        if (mimetype && extname) { 
            return cb(null, true); 
        } 
      
        cb("Error: File upload only supports the "
                + "following filetypes - " + filetypes); 
      }  
  
}).single("myfile");       

app.get("/",function(req,res){ 
    res.render("Signup"); 
}) 

app.post("/uploadCode",function (req, res, next) { 
         
    upload(req,res,function(err) { 
  
        if(err) { 
            res.send(err) 
        } 
        else { 
            res.send("Success, Image uploaded!") 
        } 
    }) 
}) 

app.listen(8000,function(error) { 
    if(error) throw error 
        console.log("Server running on port 8000") 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do the upload from a form where the browser submits the form for you automatically via a submit button, then it will be a browser form POST and the browser will automatically display whatever that POST request returns as the response.

If you, instead, upload form a form with a Javascript Ajax call to do the form POST, then the form response just comes back to your Javascript and nothing happens to the current web page in the browser.  Your Javascript can receive that response and then decide what to do with it (if anything).

You've shown your server-side code here, but it's actually the client-side that controls what happens after the response from the upload is received back from the server.  So, the changes would have to be made on the client-side to submit your form via Javascript.